# FPDF does not return to HTML

Tags: php, fpdf

I have two routines that generate separate pdf files. Each works great when I call either one of them  from my php file. But when I try to include both of them I get a blank web page. I can see the first pdf file was generated, but the second was not and then the rest of the php file does not run.

So if I comment out the pdfSETFC.php line it works fine.  If I comment out the pdfLiabilityWaiver.php line it works fine. But if both are there it fails (no error message, just a blank page).

in my php file...
`require_once 'pdfLiabilityWaiver.php';`
`require_once 'pdfSETFC.php';`

Both of my FPDF files start with this:
`require_once ("../fpdf/fpdf.php");`
`class myPDF extends FPDF {  }`
`$pdf = new myPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');`

and the last line in each is:
`$pdf->Output($filename1,'F');`

Comment: The browser's built in PDF viewer plugin isn't going to be able to display 2 PDFs in the same frame.   You can try using frames or iframes but the Edge and Chrome plugin wants to put each PDF into its own tab.  If you want to display both together you need some kind of PDF-to-HTML conversion (like a js PDF renderer separate from the built-in plugin).

Comment: If both scripts define a class with the same name, it can't work.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the name of the class in the second pdf routine and it is now working.